# TypeORM: LEFT JOINed Entity not found in WHERE

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

My service is querying with a left join another table which I want to filter in the where clause. I always get the error:

```
Property "ParentStatus.objektstatus" was not found in "Parent". Make sure your query is correct.
```

My Service in Parent looks like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class ParentService extends AbstractService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Parent)
    private readonly ourRepo: Repository<Parent>,
  ) {
    super(ourRepo);
  }

  async findAll(@Query() params?: any | null, limit: number = 25) {
    const qb = this.repository.createQueryBuilder();
    return (
      qb
        .select('Parent.id id')
        .leftJoin(
          'tbl_parent_status',
          'ParentStatus',
          'ParentStatus.id = Parent.id',
        )
 
        .where({ 'ParentStatus.objektstatus': IsNull() })
        .printSql()
        .getRawMany()
    );
  }
```

My entity Parent:

```js
@Entity({
  name: 'tbl_parent',
  schema: 'schema2',
})
export class Parent extends BaseEnt {
  @PrimaryColumn({ name: 'ID' })
  id: string;

  @OneToMany(
    () => ParentStatus,
    (parentstatus) => parentstatus.objektstatus,
  )
  related?: ParentStatus[];
}
```

And for the status:

```js
@Entity({
  name: 'tbl_parent_status',
  schema: 'schema2',
})
export class ParentStatus extends BaseEnt {

  @PrimaryColumn({ name: 'ID' })
  id: string;

  @Column({ name: 'OBJEKT_STATUS', nullable: true })
  objektstatus: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Parent, {})
  related?: Parent;
}
```

It is an oracle database in case it matters.. I tried by name and with `Raw` but it never finds the other table officially. When I comment out the `where` clause and use the created query to add the where clause manually the query works.

Update 1:
When I add `addSelect` the value of the row is coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked with a raw query like this:

```js
.where('"ParentStatus"."objektstatus" IS NULL')
```

I would still assume that the object above should also work